# How to search images files stored inside the mobile phone with PHP/HTML?

Tags: php, android, iphone, html, mobile

I'm working on a video-games based on HTML5 and PHP. We've got a lot of images on it, so we would like to suggest to our gamers, their not forced to do so, to download the image pack inside their phone in a path like 
MyPhone/DCIM/OurGame/ImagePack

If their is a images pack on the phone, then we uses it on our website, else we makes them doawnload like a regular website.

So I actually need to search inside the mobile phone for thoses files :) !
I would like to know if with PHP and HTML I can retrieve thoses images or it's blocked du to security problem.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at PhoneGap or Titanium? This would circumvent any problems you may have with browser-only app.

EDIT: Similar Idea: Make the ImagePack a service app containing a http server which provides the images at `http://localhost:<fixedPort>`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice !
We tried PhoneGap and it didnt't ended well.
Actually, we really brainstormed about that and we thought it's better if we make a "classic" HTML5 mobile game, on a browser.

Comment: http://localhost:<fixedPort> would be the path on the phone ? 
Thanks for the tip !